# the contents of arraylist are printed using println. I want a similar functionality for my created objects without using toString() function in java

Tags: java, oop, object, arraylist, tostring

[image]

In the image above, the contents of the arraylist is printed using println. I want a similar functionality for my created objects without using toString() function in java
please tell me how can i do that

Comment: When you say without using toString() you mean by not calling the method .toString() in an object?

Comment: I didn't get your question. Do you mean storing objects instead of integer or string values in ArrayList?

Comment: You have to override toString() method to your custom object

Comment: Why don't you want to override toString()?

Comment: Added a implementation that doesn't use the toString for a customClass.

Comment: Please paste your code and output into the question as text.

Answer (score -1):

To facilitate the answer, I added a CustomClazz with *toString* method and two fields(*firstField*, *secondField*) to be printed. The code uses both the `toString` method and Stream-> println of each object;

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        ArrayList<CustomClazz> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(new CustomClazz("custom1","class1"));
        list.add(new CustomClazz("custom2","class2"));
        list.add(new CustomClazz("custom3","class3"));

 //Stream that accesses and concatenates each field of custom class.. notice the bad concatenation "+"
        list.stream().map(customClass -> customClass.getFirstField()+ customClass.getSecondField()).forEach(System.out::println);

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println();
        //Option that uses the toString method of customClazz.
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(list.toArray()));
        

       
    }
}
class CustomClazz {


    String firstField;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "CustomClazz{" +
                "firstField='" + firstField + '\'' +
                ", secondField='" + secondField + '\'' +
                '}';
    }

    String secondField;
    public String getFirstField() {
        return firstField;
    }

    public void setFirstField(String firstField) {
        this.firstField = firstField;
    }

    public String getSecondField() {
        return secondField;
    }

    public void setSecondField(String secondField) {
        this.secondField = secondField;
    }
    public CustomClazz(String firstField, String secondField) {
        super();
        this.firstField = firstField;
        this.secondField = secondField;
    }
}
```

Comment: list.stream().map(customClass -> customClass.getFirstField()+ customClass.getSecondField()).forEach(System.out::println);


can u please explain this line in more detail , it will be great help

Comment: Explanation of ```stream.map```in this link https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/stream-map-java-examples/. And then the "customClass" is current Object.. THen you concatenate the firstField and secondField.. then for each element of the  map created from stream.map print out to sys out